# Where call InitializeDatabaseConnection when clientCredentialType="UserName"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

In a MVC4 app, I use the SimpleMemberShip as auth database.
The security model is:

```
<binding name="SecureBasicBindingWithMembershipConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
</binding>
```

It works fine for web page. It requires SSL and also the user log on. The problem is in the WCF services.

When I try to consume a service, I get `InvalidOperationException: You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.`

This error is correct, it means that I need to call InitializeDatabaseConnection before the server app authorizes the user credentials. Where can I call InitializeDatabaseConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it in `Global.asax` in the `Application_Start()` event:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(yourParameters);
}
```